# How to Delete files in /data/data/providers/downloads/cache on Android

Tags: java, android

I want to create and delete some files located in /data/data/providers/downloads/cache. So far, I can download target files and save in /data/data/providers/downloads/cache successfully, but when I trying to delete a file located in /data/data/providers/downloads/cache it fails in the end. My methods are as follows

```
File directory = new File("/data/data/providers/downloads/cache");
File[] files = directory.listFiles();
```

I want to list all files, so that I can find the target files need to be deleted.
I found that listFiles() method always return NULL, so my question is, can I use listFile() to the dir /data/data/providers/downloads/cache ?

Any ideals are welcomed.

BR
Alan

Comment: how did you create files in /data/data/providers. Is the phone rooted? Usually /data/data is protected and only folders that belong to the app are visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this method: when i want to delete all the files including the directory.

```
static public boolean deleteDirectory(File path) {
    if( path.exists() ) {
        File[] files = path.listFiles();
        if (files == null) {
            return true;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            if(files[i].isDirectory()) {
                deleteDirectory(files[i]);
            }
            else {
                files[i].delete();
            }
            Log.d("Deleting Files", files[i].getPath());
        }
    }

    return( path.delete() );
}
```

But android has it's own clear cache method you can use, but it requires you to actually save stuff to the cache. The problem might be that you never add anything to it, and you only have permission to clear your own cache?

[How do I take advantage of Android's "Clear Cache" button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848879/how-do-i-take-advantage-of-androids-clear-cache-button) Discusses the problem anyway :)

Good luck

EDIT:
Also, are you sure your file path is correct? You can use

```
        Environment.getDownloadCacheDirectory()
```

in order to find the root directory to the cache i think?

Comment: Thanks for you reply. 
I am sure that I gave the right file path. I just come up with another ideal, in the android system the directory of a certain app's data won't expose to the programer, like the data path /data/data/com.android/providers/downloads which is in my case.So I can't manipulate the directory with File directly. The only way to look up and delete something in the app's data path, is to use Cursor and ContentResolver. So when I use listFiles() method to a app's data path, it always return NULL.
Those are my opinions, any other opinions are welcomed.

Comment: Then it's hard for me to help you without knowing more details about the program sorry :/